# Утилита Linux cat

Tags: ubuntu, unix

Кто знаком с утилитой cat?

Вот такая инструкция:

```bash
cat log_type.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c
```

Выводит: количество повторений ip-адреса и сам ip-адрес.

Как вывести в порядке убывания?

Comment: Сортирует не 'cat', здесь цепочка команд. Символ '|' перенаправляет вывод команды на вход другой команды. Т.е. сначала отрабатывает cat, потом awk, sort, uniq. Для сортировки нужно смотреть ключи к команде 'sort'.  man sort

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

```
cat log_type.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10
```

unix под руками нет, проверял на

```
printf "10.0.10.1\n10.0.10.1\n10.0.10.3\n10.0.10.3\n10.0.10.2\n10.0.10.1"  | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -2
```

так что возможно надо будет доработать напильником

Comment: cat log_type.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10 вот немног поправил

Comment: @Foxtrot если помогло - отметьте как ответ - большой V слева, под кнопками up/down